# Django CMS Apphook does not load

Tags: python-3.5, django-cms

I have a new setup of Django CMS with the following components installed (requirements.txt):

```
Django==1.11
Pillow==5.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
django-ckeditor==5.4.0
django-cms==3.5.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor>=3.6.0
```

And the following file structure:

```
.
├── main_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── project
│   ├── cms_apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── local_settings.py
│   ├── local_settings.pyc
│   ├── production.py
│   ├── production.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── base.html
│   └── ...
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

When I add an Apphook, I cannot select the Application in the advanced page settings:
[image]

project/cms_apps.py:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool

@apphook_pool.register
class MainApphook(CMSApp):
    app_name = 'main_app'
    name = 'Main App'

    def get_urls(self, page=None, language=None, **kwargs):
        return ["main_app.urls"]
```

My installed apps in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'custom_auth',
    'djangocms_admin_style',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'treebeard',
    'sekizai',
    'ckeditor',

    'main_app',
]
```

I have restarted the server according to the tutorial at http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/apphooks.html

Note that there is no `project/cms_apps.pyc`

As far as I can tell, I followed the Apphook tutorial exactly, so what am I missing?

Comment: If `main_app` should be app hooked then it needs it's own `cms_apps.py`, not one in `project`

Comment: Oh my god, I totally misunderstood the concept there. So I would access the apps urls via main_app:my-url? Because it seems that now the referenced urls in the templates do not work when they are not namespaced.

Comment: Hopefully my answer will cover all of that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you need a `cms_apps.py` module in your app that gets hooked into the CMS.

For example I've got an app called `djangocms_forms` and it's `cms_apps.py` looks like this;

```
class DjangoCMSFormsApphook(CMSApp):
    """ Add docs """
    name = _('Forms')
    urls = ['djangocms_forms.urls']


apphook_pool.register(DjangoCMSFormsApphook)
```

It has the following URLs;

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^forms/submit/$', FormSubmission.as_view(),
        name='djangocms_forms_submissions'),
    url(r'^forms/redirect/$', media_redireect,
        name='djangocms_forms_redirect')
]
```

Those URLs are then accessed without any namespacing like `reverse('djangocms_forms_submissions')`

However you can add the namespacing by adding the `app_name` attribute to the `CMSApp`. For example I've got another app, `gallery` which is configured like;

```
class GalleryApp(CMSApp):
    """ Gallery CMS app """
    app_name = 'gallery'
    name = _("Gallery App")
    urls = ["gallery.urls"]
```

URLs for this app then are defined like, `{% url "gallery:filterable_gallery_data" %}` or in python as `reverse('gallery:filterable_gallery_data')`